# Join/Merge 2 data frames by different columns based on available values in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to join the persons data frame with the colour_match data frame, so that the person data frame will have an additional column "favourite_colour".

```
    first_name <- c("Nick", "Emily", "Joe", "Kate", "Kate", "Nick", "Joe")
    last_name <- c("Smith", "Doe", "Lee", "Jackson", "Deng", "Smith", "Lee")
    age <- c(28, 30, 52, 18, 42, 28, 52)
    pet <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit","Cat", "Mouse", "Snake", "Bird")

    person_pet <- data.frame(first_name, last_name, age, pet)
```

[image: person_pet]

```
first_name <- c("Emily","Nick", "Kate", "Joe", "Kate")
last_name <- c("Doe", "Smith", NA, "Lee", NA)
age <- c(NA, NA, 42, 52, 29)
favourite_colour <- c("black", "yellow", "red", "green", "white")

colour_match <- data.frame(first_name, last_name, age, favorite_colour)
```

[image: colour_match]

The challenge is that I will need to join by as many columns as possible as long as the column has a value in the colour_match data frame. The available columns in the colour_match table determines the "join columns" between the two tables. For example, for "Nick Smith", join by first_name and last_name; for "Joe Lee", join by all three columns; . In the end, the result should look like below:
[image: person_favourite_colour]

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a small helper function which checks the availability of possible join columns and then joins by all available ones. This function then gets called for each row separately and the result is concatenated again.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyr)

first_name <- c("Nick", "Emily", "Joe", "Kate", "Kate")
last_name <- c("Smith", "Doe", "Lee", "Jackson", "Deng")
age <- c(28, 30, 52, 18, 42)

persons <- tibble(first_name, last_name, age)

first_name <- c("Nick", "Emily", "Joe", "Kate", "Kate")
last_name <- c("Smith", NA, NA, "Jackson", NA)
age <- c(NA, NA, 52, 18, 29)
favorite_colour <- c("black", "yellow", "red", "green", "white")

colour_match <- tibble(first_name, last_name, age, favorite_colour)

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# helper function
join_if_available <- function(x, y) {
  
  # define possible set of join cols
  join_cols <- c("first_name", "last_name", "age")
  
  # check which (if any) col is missing
  missing <- which(is.na(y[join_cols]))
  
  if (length(missing) > 0) {
    
    # remove missing index and then only keep the available join cols
    # plus the favorite_colour col 
    join_cols <- join_cols[-missing]
    y <- dplyr::select(y, join_cols, favorite_colour)
    
  }
  
  # perform a simple left join
  out <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, by = join_cols)
  
  return(out)
  
}

# split each data frame by row, iterate over each row separately,
# then rowbind the result
purrr::map2_dfr(.x = split(persons, 1:nrow(persons)),
                .y = split(colour_match, 1:nrow(colour_match)),
                .f = ~ join_if_available(x = .x, y = .y))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   first_name last_name   age favorite_colour
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          
#> 1 Nick       Smith        28 black          
#> 2 Emily      Doe          30 yellow         
#> 3 Joe        Lee          52 red            
#> 4 Kate       Jackson      18 green          
#> 5 Kate       Deng         42 <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: would this not only compare row 1 to row 1, row 2 to row 2 etc?  What if there's a missing value in one or the other frame? Or if they are differently ordered?

Comment: True, this is tailored to OP's setup where each row is in the "correct" order in both data frames and missings can only occur in the `colour_match` (aka `y`) data frame. But it's possible to extend the function to check for missings in both `x` and `y` (or rather the overlap of missings), and the order could be handled by sorting the rows beforehand.

Comment: @henhesu, thank you for the solution. I can see how it would work for the example. I should have provided a better example closer to the actual scenario I'm trying to solve. The "persons" data frame actually is more like a Fact table that has many rows for a given "person", and the colour_match table is more like a reference table and has much fewer rows. I tried to use apply (apply(X = persons, MARGIN = 1, FUN = join_if_available , y = colour_match) rather than map2_dfr when using the function, but got an error "no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "character"